# Functional programming in C#, how can I convert this imperative method into functional approach?

Tags: c#, functional-programming

I'm trying to convert my business logics, and many of my code are like this:

```
public Result1 Logic1(int a)
{
  var b = ComputeByA(a);
  var c = ComputeByB(b);
  var d = ComputeByC(c);
  return new Result1()
  {
    B = b, C = c, D = d
  }
}

public Result2 Logic2(int a)
{
  var b = ComputeByA(a);
  var e = ComputeByB2(b);
  var f = ComputeByE(e);
  return new Result2()
  {
    B = b, E = e, F = f
  }
}
```

I need to compute values that dependent by other values, and I need them all.
And some methods are reused many times, others are only used in the domain.

I tried like this :

```
public Result1 Logic1(int a)
{
  return 
    ComputeByA(a)
      .ComputeByB(b)
      .ComputeByC(c)
      .ToResult();
}
```

That method computes values well, but I cannot find good (or 'elegant') way to store b and c for result during function chains.
How can I do this?

Comment: What you have looks fine to me. Not everything needs to be written in functional style.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Thomas and have two questions for you: 1) why do you want to change to functional programming? And 2) Is the switch major enough that you could change language? If I recall correctly, F# for example is designed to be a lot better for functional programming.

Comment: @Traveller 1. the example is much simplified.  real logic has bunch of temporary variables and dependent to 'external' variables(such as class fields), then I thought functional style is better for readablity and maintainablity. 2. Unfortunately, I have to use C# now.

Comment: Is there any possibility of splitting the classes and methods up some more or something? If the issue is too many similarly-named variables and unmanageable code, that's the direction I'd try to go with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish, but I appreciate that the OP isn't your real code.

You can chain functions by echoing the input as part of the output, but in general it's not a good idea, because it's going to make the code inflexible. Unless you have very specific requirements, it's probably a better idea to **go with what you already have**.

Situations where the following may be appropriate is if you have to build an object piecemeal and you want to use the static type system to ensure that all steps have been invoked.

You can use custom types (classes, structs, or records) to echo back the input together with the output, or you can use tuples. Here I've just used tuples:

```
public static B ComputeByA(int a)
{
    return new B();
}

public static (B, C) ComputeByB(this B b)
{
    return (b, new C());
}

public static (B, E) ComputeByB2(this B b)
{
    return (b, new E());
}

public static Result1 ComputeByC(this (B b, C c) tuple)
{
    return new Result1(tuple.b, tuple.c, new D());
}

public static Result2 ComputeByE(this (B b, E e) tuple)
{
    return new Result2(tuple.b, tuple.e, new F());
}
```

This now gives you the ability to chain functions together:

```
public static Result1 Logic1(int a)
{
    return ComputeByA(a).ComputeByB().ComputeByC();
}

public static Result2 Logic2(int a)
{
    return ComputeByA(a).ComputeByB2().ComputeByE();
}
```

Again, unless you have specific reasons to constrain how functions can be chained, I wouldn't recommend an API design like this. If, for example, `ComputeByC` only requires `C`, then forcing callers to supply both `B` and `C`  is unwarranted.

Comment: Could have made `ComputeByA` an extension method too, then it would look even nicer: `a.ComputeByA().ComputeByB()....` (assuming people are OK with extending `int`)

Comment: Is it OK that keeping a kind of context? (tuples, structs, or something) ?

Comment: @leffe I don't understand the question. Can you elaborate (perhaps in a new post)?